# error in global.asax and how to store the data from database

Tags: php

I got the error in global.asax and how to store the data from database and this is trying myself

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Routing;



 namespace DemoApplication
 {
     public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
     {        
         protected void Application_Start()
         {
             AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
             RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
         }
        public void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
         {
             if (!Settings.initialized)
             {
                 new Settings().Init();
             }
         }
     }
     public partial class Settings
     {
         public static bool UseProducts { get; set; }
         public static int SiteID { get; set; }

         public static bool initialized;

         /// Constructor
         public Settings()
         {
             initialized = false;
         }

         /// Initializes the class
         public void Init()
         {
             if (!initialized)
                 RetrieveAllSettings();
             initialized = true;
         }

         /// Loads all the settings from the db
         private void RetrieveAllSettings()
         {
             DataContext db = new DataContext();
             var settingval = (from s in db.websiteSettings
                               select s).SingleOrDefault();

             if (settingval != null)
             {
                 UseProducts = settingval.UseProducts;
                 SiteID = settingval.SiteID;
             }

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly might have shortened the title a little as well while editing

Comment: @RST Feel free to edit my edit

Comment: thank you where it is shortend

Comment: What is the question? And what errors are you getting? There is way too little information that explains your intentions and problems to help you. Remember: We're not mind readers.

Comment: DataContext db = new DataContext();
             var settingval = (from s in db.websiteSettings
                               select s).SingleOrDefault();
This part showing Error 4 The type or namespace name 'DataContext' could not be found  and websittings not found

Comment: Any body is there answer the Question

Answer (score 0):

you should change the tag, it's not even sonme php here